# TikZ connecting lines and nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

my question is the following: as you can see in the code below I placed some nodes and want to connect them with lines. But so far I was not able to let all the lines start/ end at the same point. So there are always holes and I have no clue how to avoid them.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=center] (1) at (0,5) {};
        \node[above left=1 and 1 of 1.center,anchor=center] (11) {};
        \node[above left =1 and 0.5 of 1.center,anchor=center] (12) {};
        \draw (1) -- (11);
        \draw (1) -- (12);
    \node[anchor=center] (2) at (5,3) {};
        \node[above right=1 and 1 of 2.center,anchor=center] (21) {};
        \node[above right=0.5 and 1 of 2.center,anchor=center] (22) {};
        \draw (2) -- (21);
        \draw (2) -- (22);
    \draw (1) -- (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  `\node`'s usually have a non-zero `inner sep`.  You probably want to use `\coordinate`'s instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shorter and correct:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (1) at (0,5);
    \draw (1) -- ++ (-1.0,1);
    \draw (1) -- ++ (-0.5,1);
\coordinate (2) at (5,3);
    \node[above right=1 and 1 of 2.center,anchor=center] (21) {};
    \node[above right=0.5 and 1 of 2.center,anchor=center] (22) {};
    \draw (2) -- ++ (1.0,1);
    \draw (2) -- ++ (0.5,1);
\draw (1) -- (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]